Weird memory leak in Valgrind in a print function
So this is a C script for managing parking lots, and I have this struct:
typedef struct {
    char name[MAXSIZE];
    int capacity;
    char car_plates[MAXREGISTRATIONS][PLATE_SIZE];
    char entry_dates[MAXREGISTRATIONS][DATE_SIZE];
    char entry_hours[MAXREGISTRATIONS][HOUR_SIZE];
    char exit_date[DATE_SIZE]; 
    char exit_hour[HOUR_SIZE];
    float value_15_minutes;
    float value_after_1_hour;
    float max_daily_value;
    float revenue;
    int available_spaces;
} ParkingLot;
int num_parks = 0;
ParkingLot parks[MAXPARKS];

And I have this function called create park, that works well:
void createParking(char name[], int capacity, float value_15_minutes, float value_after_1_hour, float max_daily_value) {
    if (num_parks >= MAXPARKS) {
        printf("Too many parks.\n");
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num_parks; i++) {
        if (strcmp(parks[i].name, name) == 0) {
            printf("%s: Parking already exists.\n", name);
            return;
        }
    }
    if(capacity <= 0){
        printf("%d: Invalid capacity.\n", capacity);
        return;
    }
    if (value_15_minutes <= 0 || value_after_1_hour <= value_15_minutes || max_daily_value <= value_after_1_hour) {
        printf("Invalid cost.\n");
        return;
    }

    strcpy(parks[num_parks].name, name);
    parks[num_parks].capacity = capacity;
    parks[num_parks].value_15_minutes = value_15_minutes;
    parks[num_parks].value_after_1_hour = value_after_1_hour;
    parks[num_parks].max_daily_value = max_daily_value;
    parks[num_parks].available_spaces = capacity;


    num_parks++;
}

So this is just for context, that function is not the problem, the problem is that I'm getting memory leaks in my code, and I think that's weird considering I have zero mallocs.This is the Valgrind report, and all the functions that are issued
==3537366== 4,096 bytes in 1 block are still reachable in loss record 32 of 32
==3537366==    at 0x4843828: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3537366==    by 0x48D6633: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==3537366==    by 0x48E65AF: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==3537366==    by 0x48E550F: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:744)
==3537366==    by 0x48E3CE4: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1243)
==3537366==    by 0x48E3CE4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1196)
==3537366==    by 0x48B4AA0: __printf_buffer_flush_to_file (printf_buffer_to_file.c:59)
==3537366==    by 0x48B4AA0: __printf_buffer_to_file_done (printf_buffer_to_file.c:120)
==3537366==    by 0x48BEB48: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1460)
==3537366==    by 0x498B63A: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:33)
==3537366==    by 0x10C6F8: printf (stdio2.h:86)
==3537366==    by 0x10C6F8: list_parks (project.c:429)
==3537366==    by 0x10C6F8: command_p (project.c:978)
==3537366==    by 0x109377: main (project.c:1275)


int main() {
   
    
    while (1) {
        char command[50];
        scanf("%s", command);
        if (strcmp(command, "q") == 0) {
            release_daily_revenue(&daily_revenue);
            
            break;
        }
        check_input(command);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void command_p(char command[]) {
    int rc;
    char name[MAXSIZE];
    float capacity;
    float value_15, value_15_after_1_hour, max_daily_value;

    if (strcmp(command, "p") == 0) {
        char nextChar = getchar();
        if (nextChar == '\n') {
            list_parks();
        } else {
            ungetc(nextChar, stdin);
            char str[MAXSIZE * 5]; // Increasing the size to handle complete input
            if (fgets(str, MAXSIZE * 5, stdin) == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            
            if ((rc = sscanf(str, "%s %f %f %f %f", name, &capacity, &value_15, &value_15_after_1_hour, &max_daily_value)) != 5) {
                rc = sscanf(str, " \"%[^\"]\" %f %f %f %f", name, &capacity, &value_15, &value_15_after_1_hour, &max_daily_value);
            
           
            createParking(name, (int)capacity, value_15, value_15_after_1_hour, max_daily_value);
        }
    }
}

void list_parks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_parks; i++) {
        printf("%s %d %d\n", parks[i].name, parks[i].capacity, parks[i].available_spaces);
    }
    return;
}


The valgrind report says I'm losing 4096 bytes in 1 block in the list_parks function which I can't understand how it's happening, and another 4096 bytes lost (that are still reachable), totalling 10,553 bytes in 164 blocks (some other minor leaks in the rest of the code ). Can you please help me out figuring what the hell is going on here

Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

As a probable reason, the first call to the printf function will create the internal data structures and buffers needed for stdout. These will be used all throughout the process execution, and will be released when the process exit (by the operating system).

I would love to, but I don't know what's going on. This is a project for college and when I submit it this report shows. I don't know what to do, just trying to get an hint.

@Someprogrammerdude okay, so basically the MAXSIZE was defined to 10000, and I changed it to 5000, and for some reason that solved the problem... would still like to know how this can happen. Anyways thank you for your help

BTW: there is no such thing as a "C script".

What OS are you using? Which version of Valgrind?

My guess would be similar to what @Someprogrammerdude said. False positive because calling printf for the first time lazily allocated some internal structure it needs to operate.

In the light of the recent liblzma debacle don't be in a hurry to listen to people saying problems are false positives.
Also a 'minimum reproducible example' is no substitute for knowing how Valgrind works.
The comments are right that this is a one-off allocation done for I/O buffering by GNU libc. For some reason (perhaps you are using a version of Valgrind that is too old) Valgrind is not running the glibc cleanup function. It's also possible that there is a defect in your glibc and it isn't freeing memory with __libc_freeres. If, for any reason, you can't get the freeres mechanism to work then you should consider using the suppression mechanism.
If you run valgrind -v -v [your exe] you should see something like
--16708-- Caught __NR_exit; running __gnu_cxx::__freeres and __libc_freeres() wrapper

Here are a few examples.
The canonical C "Hello World"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

I'm running Valgrind from its build directory, you should replace 'vg-in-place' with 'valgrind'.
~/valgrind/vg-in-place -v -v ./hw
...
Hello, World!
--340-- Caught __NR_exit; running __gnu_cxx::__freeres and __libc_freeres() wrapper
--340-- REDIR: 0x48fbe20 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4846996 (free)
==340== 
==340== HEAP SUMMARY:
==340==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==340==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==340== 
==340== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==340== 
==340== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

You can see here that printf caused 1k to be allocated which was freed by __libc_freeres.
I can turn off the use of __libc_freeres with --run-libc-freeres=no. that gives me
~/valgrind/vg-in-place -v -v --run-libc-freeres=no --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./hw
...
Hello, World!
--359-- Caught __NR_exit; running __gnu_cxx::__freeres() wrapper
==359== 
==359== HEAP SUMMARY:
==359==     in use at exit: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==359==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==359== 
==359== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x10c000..0x10cfff (4096)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x4035000..0x4036fff (8192)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x4037000..0x4037fff (4096)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x483b000..0x483bfff (4096)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x483c000..0x483dfff (8192)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x4858000..0x4858fff (4096)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x4a38000..0x4a39fff (8192)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x4a3a000..0x4a44fff (45056)
--359--   Scanning root segment: 0x1ffeffe000..0x1fff000fff (12288)
==359== Checked 83,688 bytes
==359== 
==359== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==359==    at 0x484378B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==359==    by 0x48D5F19: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==359==    by 0x48E4C88: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==359==    by 0x48E4C88: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:342)
==359==    by 0x48E2DF7: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:745)
==359==    by 0x48E38D6: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1244)
==359==    by 0x48E38D6: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==359==    by 0x48D86E8: puts (ioputs.c:40)
==359==    by 0x10914B: main (hw.c:5)
==359== 
==359== LEAK SUMMARY:
==359==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359==    still reachable: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==359==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359== 
==359== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Finally, freeing up glibc resources doesn't get done if the test executable terminates with a fatal signal.
For instance
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>


int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
   kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
}

This gives
Hello, World!
==390== 
==390== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==390==    at 0x489C9AB: kill (syscall-template.S:120)
==390==    by 0x10917C: main (hw.c:10)
==390== 
==390== HEAP SUMMARY:
==390==     in use at exit: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==390==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==390== 
==390== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x10c000..0x10cfff (4096)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x4035000..0x4036fff (8192)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x4037000..0x4037fff (4096)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x483b000..0x483bfff (4096)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x483c000..0x483dfff (8192)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x4858000..0x4858fff (4096)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x4a38000..0x4a39fff (8192)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x4a3a000..0x4a44fff (45056)
--390--   Scanning root segment: 0x1ffeffe000..0x1fff000fff (12288)
==390== Checked 83,600 bytes
==390== 
==390== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==390==    at 0x484378B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==390==    by 0x48D5F19: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==390==    by 0x48E4C88: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==390==    by 0x48E4C88: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:342)
==390==    by 0x48E2DF7: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:745)
==390==    by 0x48E38D6: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1244)
==390==    by 0x48E38D6: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==390==    by 0x48D86E8: puts (ioputs.c:40)
==390==    by 0x10916B: main (hw.c:9)
==390== 
==390== LEAK SUMMARY:
==390==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==390==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==390==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==390==    still reachable: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==390==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==390== 
==390== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Without more details of your OS, compiler and Valgrind version I can't say why you are not seeing the memory get freed.
